# Leaflet.imageOverlay gets lagging when showing large images

Tags: vue.js, leaflet

I'm new to Leaflet. So I had some trouble when trying to show multiple image overlays in the leaflet. My map has to load and show about 1 - 3000 overlays simultaneously (max resolution: 5000 x 8000, size: 300KB to 2MB [per ovelay]). All images are requested from an API (in base64 encode).

Can you give me some ways to optimise this? My overlays should be displayed on the map with lat_lng_bounds (north, west, south, east) so that I cannot use the leaflet_pixi_overlay library in this case.

The project is coding in VueJS (lang: TS)

Thanks for your help!
Regards.

I have tried the leaflet_pixi_overlay and blob but it still lag. And I want to optimise this a little bit smoother or can interact with the map when the overlays are rendering.

Answer (score -2):

Handling a large number of overlays in Leaflet can be challenging, especially when dealing with thousands of image overlays simultaneously. Here are some strategies to optimize the rendering performance and interaction:

1. Use Tile Layers:
   Instead of adding thousands of individual image overlays, consider using Tile Layers. Break down the large image into smaller tiles (256x256 pixels or 512x512 pixels) and serve them as a set of small images. Leaflet has built-in support for Tile Layers, and this approach can significantly improve performance, especially when dealing with large images.
2. Implement Image Tiling:
   If your images can be split into tiles, you can dynamically load and display only the necessary tiles within the viewable bounds of the map. This technique, similar to how maps are displayed using map tiles, can greatly reduce initial loading times and improve interaction.
3. Implement Clustering:
   If showing thousands of markers or overlays simultaneously is necessary, consider implementing clustering techniques to group nearby overlays into clusters. Leaflet has plugins like `MarkerCluster` that help manage large numbers of markers effectively.
4. Use Web Workers:
   Consider using Web Workers to offload heavy computation tasks related to image processing or overlay rendering. Web Workers allow parallel execution, preventing UI thread blocking and enhancing the overall responsiveness of the application.
5. Optimize Image Loading:
   Optimize your images for web usage to reduce file size without compromising quality. Use formats like `WebP` or `JPG` 2000 or optimize JPEG/PNG images using tools like `ImageMagick` or `TinyPNG` to reduce file sizes without losing much quality.
6. Implement Progressive Loading:
   Load images progressively or incrementally based on the map's viewport. Initially, load lower resolution or fewer overlays and progressively load additional overlays as the user interacts or moves around the map.
7. Testing and Performance Profiling:
   Regularly test the application's performance and use browser developer tools to profile the application for any bottlenecks or areas where optimizations can be applied. This will help identify specific areas that need improvement.
8. Utilize Virtual Rendering:
   Implement a virtual rendering technique where only the overlays within the visible map area are rendered, dynamically updating as the map moves or zooms. Libraries like `Mapbox GL JS` and `Deck.gl` handle large data sets efficiently using this method.

Remember, handling a large number of overlays or markers efficiently can be complex and might require a combination of strategies. Experimentation and testing will help determine the most effective approach for your specific scenario.